# How can I embed an image in tinymce?

Tags: tinymce, embed

Tinymce allows you to add an image by refering to an url. For a normal user, who probably does not even know what an url is, this is too tedious. They have an image on their computer, and it should be embedded in the html text. Is there a straightforward way to achieve this using tinymce?

A file upload plugin would not be helpful in this particular instance, because the tinymce editor runs locally. The image really needs to be *embedded* in the html text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that in the tinymce init valid_elements and valid_children are configured correctly. How do you wish the user to embed the image? (buttonclick, drag-and-drop,...)

To insert an image per tinymce API you can use:

```
editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<img src="images/myimage.jpeg" height="12" width="12" />');
```

I strongly suggest you download the tinymce developer version and have a closer look at the files tiny_mce/themes/advanced/editor_template_src.js and tiny_mce/themes/advanced/charmap.html. If possible search the sourcecode for "charmap".
Instead inserting a character you will have to insert the image html code.

Comment: I would like to use an "insert image" button. Of course, drag-and-drop would be neat! But a button is probably easier to discover, and would not necessitate any special training.

Comment: so in this case clicking the button would insert one single image (the same) or trigger a dialogue to choose one?

Comment: A dialogue to choose a file upon pressing the "insert image" button is what I am aiming for.

Comment: You should have a look at the charmap button (advanced feature). This is a good starting point. See my edited post.

Comment: Thanks, Thariama. What you outline sounds like the correct path to go. Unfortunately, I don't do any work in Javascript on a daily basis, so I may not be able to invest the time necessary to implement this feature myself. I may end up helping customers to insert images "by hand" for the time being. Thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 2):

I have created a plugin its found here ( https://github.com/buddyexpress/bdesk_photo )

There are some restrictions in plugin like:

- The image must be equal to or less then 500KB
- The image must be equal to or less then 800x800 in dimensions.